# php mysql where IN clause

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have a simple query:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

SELECT *  FROM pages WHERE user_id IN($user_id);
```

field user_id in pages tables has the following format 1,3,5,...
it contains multiple user_id

What I need is to select all rows based on logged in user_id. 
The above attempt does not works, it only picks up the first number.

Comment: Beware SQL injections when putting user input in SQL queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `find_in_set()`:

```
select *
from pages
where find_in_set(user_id, $user_id) > 0;
```

Alternatively, you can construct the SQL so it has the values in the string.  Something like:

```
select *
from pages
where user_id in (".$user_id.")"
```

Comment: Thanks, it works only if I reverse variables like:
find_in_set($user_id, user_id) > 0